# Securing login redirects

Tags: internet

If somebody were accessing a protected page while logged out, they would be redirected to a login page:

```
/login?next=/something/123/manage?sort=desc
```

If a successful login, they should be redirected to the page they have been intending to view:

```
if verify_creds(user, password):
    login(user)
    return redirect(request.args['next'])
```

How to verify that an attacker cannot use the next parameter to visit a phishing site? Is it sufficient to check if next starts with `/`, ie a relative link or should I try to check if its a valid path in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it sufficient to check if next starts with `/`, ie a relative link

No, it's not sufficient. Take this script as an example:

```
<?php header('Location: ' . $_GET['next']); ?>
```

An attacker could trigger an open redirect via `redirect.php?next=//example.com/`. You browser interprets this as an absolute URL using the same protocol.

> should I try to check if its a valid path in my application?

That would be the most secure solution. If checking valid paths is not an option, you should instead make sure the URL starts with `/[a-zA-Z0-9]` (that is one slash and one alphanumeric character).

Checking that it starts with `/` and not with `//`, as suggested by @BenoitEsnard, might be secure in some contexts but it's not always sufficient. Take this example (and ignore the obvious XSS problem for argument's sake):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php echo $_GET['next']; ?>">
```

Here, an attacker could achieve a redirect via `redirect.php?next=/%26sol;example.com/` which HTML-encodes the second `/` and wouldn't be picked up by a filter that checks for a `//` beginning.

The [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) on unvalidated redirects has some additional advice.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not enough to check that `next` starts with `/`.

Protocol-relative URLs, like `//example.org` could be used to bypass this check, and redirect the user to an external domain.

Checking that the URL starts with `/` and doesn't start with `//` should fully mitigate this issue.